# How to override method of the logging module

Tags: python, django

I want to count the number of times `logger.info` and `logger.error` has been hit. 
I am planning to override default method error of logging, Can anyone suggest me how to do that ? 
Need help to override error method so that every time code hit it count the value and increment counter.

Comment: Can you share any code you've tried? You could start by just adding your own `MyLogger` that wraps python's logger implementation and adds counters.

Answer (score 21):

You can firstly implement your own logger class by deriving from logging.Logger, in which you override the methods you target. And then you pass the logger class to the logging system by using [logging.setLoggerClass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.setLoggerClass).  With this setting, the logger objects instantiated from logging.getLogger will be of your class.

**update with sample code based on request**:

```
import logging
import threading

class MyLogger(logging.Logger):

    def __init__(self, name, level = logging.NOTSET):
        self._count = 0
        self._countLock = threading.Lock()       

        return super(MyLogger, self).__init__(name, level)        

    @property
    def warnCount(self):
        return self._count

    def warning(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):
        self._countLock.acquire()
        self._count += 1
        self._countLock.release()

        return super(MyLogger, self).warning(msg, *args, **kwargs)

logging.setLoggerClass(MyLogger)
logging.basicConfig()


'''testing below'''

logger = logging.getLogger('loggerX')
assert isinstance(logger, MyLogger)

logger.warning('1st warning')
logger.warning('2nd warning')
print logger.warnCount
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your idea. I tried but failed to do the same. I am learning python and new to it. 
Can you please give me the code for this Lei Shi. It would be really useful.

Comment: Does this code make any sense ? 

#!/usr/bin/python

import logging

QUERY_COUNT = 0
original_function = logging.error._obj

class MyLogger:
    def _obj(self, meth, *args):
        conn = self.getConnection()
        val = meth(conn, *args)
        self.releaseConnection(conn)
        return val
    
    def wrapper(self, meth, *args):
        global QUERY_COUNT
        QUERY_COUNT += 1
        return original_function(self, meth, *args)

logging.error._obj = wrapper

Comment: @PrashantRathi, please check my updated answer for the sample code

Comment: AMAZING!!! it worked .... Hats off. You are genius ......Can you please suggest me some good link or site to increase my level of coding in Python like you ? Or any video tutorial to get good hold on it?

Where are you based of BTW?

Comment: @PrashantRathi , to be honest,  I don't have any good recommendations. I learned Python by working on some projects as well as reading the office docs, but I'm not sure whether this way could be applied to you. I'm based in Shanghai

Comment: And if you find the answer to your logging question works for you, you may accept it. Thanks:)

Comment: Hi Lei, Hope you are doing well. I was learning new thing and got stuck, need your help. How can I use default function of any module and using that implement my own function with extended functionality. For example: I was to use info method from logging and was to create a pass function using that and add some extra functionality.

Comment: Dear Lei, 
I hope you are the right person in my contact to answer this question. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38524483/how-to-write-mock-stud-for-server-python-script

Your help would be really appreciated.

Comment: in django, how do implement this code ? [lei Shi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4328122/lei-shi)

Answer (score 0):

If you planning to override a default logging module, you have to override `logging.Handler` class. `logging.Handler` class have a function called `emit(self, record)` that will be called when we use log functionality in our Django view like this,

```
# import the logging library
import logging

# Get an instance of a logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def my_view(request, arg1, arg):
    ...
    if bad_mojo:
        # Log an error message
        logger.error('Something went wrong!')
```

### overriding `logging.Handler` class

for my specific requirement, I'm logging message in a database by creating object of `ErrorLog`  but you want to do console, print or even email that you do can do also. by doing an error log in a database you can count `logger.info` and `logger.errors`

```
import logging
import traceback


class ErrorLogHandler(logging.Handler):

def emit(self, record):
    '''this each method called when a log creates '''
    from ..models.error_log import ErrorLog
    # for more info you can use this thing from record object
    # print('levelname', record.levelname)
    # print('filename', record.filename)
    # print('funcName', record.funcName)
    # print('lineno', record.lineno)
    # print('module', record.module)
    # print('args', record.args)
    # print('exc_info', record.exc_info)
    # print('msg', record.msg)

    trace = None
    user_master = None

    if record.exc_info:
        trace = traceback.format_exc()

    if record.args and type(record.args) == dict:
        user_master = record.args.get('user_master')

    kwargs = {
        'logger_name': record.name,
        'level': record.levelname,
        'message': record.msg,
        'function_name': record.funcName,
        'file_name': record.filename,
        'trace': trace,
        'user_master': user_master
    }

    ErrorLog.objects.create(**kwargs)
```

in `settings.py` you have to override settings of logging

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {  # this will handle (called) log initialize
        'db_log': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'servicesApp.logging.handler.ErrorLogHandler'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'db': {  # for django app logs
            'handlers': ['db_log'],
            'level': 'INFO'
        },
    }
}
```